# Could neither find styled-components secret internals

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, styled-components

I'm currently trying to update to Styled Components 5.0.0 but I've had some issues that my JEST tests stops working. I've downgraded down to 4.2.1, but still updated babel@preset-react, preset-env, core and some other packages. I get this error when I try run npm test:

"Could neither find styled-components secret internals" and it points to `import 'jest-styled-components';` Jest-styled-components is also updated to 7.0.0

Comment: For all to know, there is an open issue on github speaking about it [here](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/297).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/301#issuecomment-893170436

> Change to yarn add jest-styled-components@6.3.4 solve the issue.